# Cómo utilizar un JButton para acceder a un método de JDBC en otra clase distinta?

Tags: java, java-swing, jdbc

Editaré gran parte de mí pregunta.

Cree una interfaz gráfica con el gestor de netbeans, esta tiene un par de label y textfield.
NOMBRE, RUT, DIRECCIÓN, BUSCAR NOMBRE. Y además posee un botón para buscar.

Además de la clase de la interfaz gráfica tengo una clase que tiene los métodos de conexión y busqueda en la base de datos.

De ésta forma no me funciona.

```
package crudvilcun;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Metodos {

    public static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tienda";
    public static final String username = "root";
    public static final String password = "";
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    GUI contenido;

    public Connection Conexion() {

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
        }

        return con;
    }

    public void BuscarRegistro() {

        try {
            con = Conexion();
            ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select * from personas where nombre like '"+contenido.txtBuscar.getText()+ "'");
//            ps.setString(1, contenido.txtBuscar.getText());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("nombre"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("direccion"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("rut"));
//                contenido.txtNombre.setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
//                contenido.txtDireccion.setText(rs.getString("direccion"));
//                contenido.txtRut.setText(rs.getString("rut"));

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
        }

    }

}
```

Descubrí que el error está en ésta linea

```
 ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select * from personas where nombre like '"+contenido.txtBuscar.getText()+ "'");
```

Ya que reemplacé la query por un dato que estaba dentro de la tabla.("select * from personas where nombre like 'jorge martini'") y funcionó a la perfección.

Imprimió por consola los datos almacenados en la base de datos.

Pero al momento de querer introducir esos datos a los textfield con setText.

Me arrojó otro error.

```
JORGE MARTINI
LOS TINEOS 140
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
195194467
    at crudvilcun.Metodos.BuscarRegistro(Metodos.java:45)
    at crudvilcun.GUI.btnBuscarActionPerformed(GUI.java:112)
    at crudvilcun.GUI.access$000(GUI.java:12)
    at crudvilcun.GUI$1.actionPerformed(GUI.java:54)
```

Comment: El error tambien estaba en la URL que te faltaban dos punbtos campeón ;) ya veo que lo arreglaste jajaja

Comment: Te da error de NullPointerException por que cuando se ejecuta una vez el rs.getString, ya está hecho y no puedes volver a hacerlo por que ya has leido uno de los datos que almacena el ResultSet
Mira a ver si es por eso y si no me corriges que estoy casi igual que tú, saludos.

Comment: @DazzelWazzel Si, tenía montones de errores JAJAJAJ

Comment: Cuando lo hice, no había puesto el system.out.println